# Adding element to an ArrayList received as argument in recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, pass-by-reference

I have a method which performs permutation of an `ArrayList` elements, I give an ArrayList as parameter where to store the permutations. However, it's always adding the same item.

I think the issue about this is the ArrayList *reference*.

```
public class TSP {

    static ArrayList permute(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int k, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> resultados) {
        for(int i = k; i < arr.size(); i++){
            java.util.Collections.swap(arr, i, k);
            permute(arr, k+1, resultados);
            java.util.Collections.swap(arr, k, i);
        }

        if (k == arr.size() -1){

            System.out.println("Permute method: "+arr.toString());
            resultados.add(arr);
        }
        return resultados;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

            ArrayList<Integer> ciudades = new ArrayList<>();
            ciudades.add(1);
            ciudades.add(2);
            ciudades.add(3);
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> resultados = new ArrayList();
            resultados = permute(ciudades, 0, resultados);

            for (ArrayList<Integer> resultado : resultados) {
                System.out.println(resultado.toString());
            }
    }
}
```

The output from execution is:

> Permute method: [1, 2, 3]
>   Permute method: [1, 3, 2]
>   Permute method: [2, 1, 3]
>   Permute method: [2, 3, 1]
>   Permute method: [3, 2, 1]
>   Permute method: [3, 1, 2]
>   [1, 2, 3]
>   [1, 2, 3]
>   [1, 2, 3]
>   [1, 2, 3]
>   [1, 2, 3]
>   [1, 2, 3]

So everything's working OK *inside the algorithm* but only the first permutation is added. ***Why?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it's the ArrayList reference. It's always pointed to the same object in memory, so the permute is always effecting ALL of the arrays in resultado. (Since they are all the same reference).

Changing the add line to:

```
resultados.add((ArrayList<Integer>)arr.clone());
```

will instead add a copy of the permuted array to resultados, and get you the output you're expecting.